# Meaning of "no telling whether good or evil."

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> As I stood there telling my parents that I had returned and what I meant to
>   do, I noticed a movement among the bushes. I was ready to run back to the
>   truck when Kanoro stepped out. Or I thought it was Kanoro, the Kanoro
>   whom I recalled from my childhood.
>   “Bibi Rachel?” He backed away from me as if I were a spirit, and **no
>   telling whether good or evil**.

Dose it mean:  I didn't know he had seen good sprit or evil sprit??

Source: Listening for Lions by
Gloria Whelan

Answer (score -1):

'...as if I were a spirit, and he could not tell whether it was a good spirit or an evil one.'

Comment: Dose it mean: he did not realize whether he had seen me or my sprit???

Comment: I  haven't read the book, but it seems to mean that he behaved as though the speaker were a spirit (ghost).